Unable to access deployed app on PythonAnywhere
I created and deployed a Taipy app using PythonAnywhere a couple of weeks ago. It was working fine. I just went to the URL  ( https://taupirho/pythonanywhere.com) again today for the first time since and I'm getting,
This site can’t be reached
taupirho’s server IP address could not be found.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
My internet connection is fine for other URLs and I'm able to log in the PythonAnywhere website no problem today
Last few lines of server log
2024-11-16 13:53:43 *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
2024-11-16 13:53:43 Python main interpreter initialized at 0x560bcd116e90
2024-11-16 13:53:43 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
2024-11-16 13:53:43 your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
2024-11-16 13:53:43 setting request body buffering size to 65536 bytes
2024-11-16 13:53:43 mapped 334256 bytes (326 KB) for 1 cores
2024-11-16 13:53:43 *** Operational MODE: single process ***
2024-11-16 13:53:43 initialized 38 metrics
2024-11-16 13:53:43 WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 7 seconds on interpreter 0x560bcd116e90 pid: 1 (default app)
2024-11-16 13:53:43 *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
2024-11-16 13:53:43 gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
2024-11-16 13:53:43 spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 12, cores: 1)
2024-11-16 13:53:43 metrics collector thread started
2024-11-16 13:53:43 spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1
2024-11-16 13:53:43 announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
last few lines of access log
5.38.181.242 - - [12/Nov/2024:19:35:12 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=uqhuz99h&sid=DDqZY_kxTB2Tec70AAAC HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "https://taupirho.pythonanywhere.com/" "donkey/4.5.1240770" "5.38.181.242" response-time=4.580
5.255.231.42 - - [14/Nov/2024:04:39:50 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)" "5.255.231.42" response-time=0.231
213.180.203.78 - - [14/Nov/2024:04:39:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1051 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)" "213.180.203.78" response-time=0.108
54.147.33.181 - - [16/Nov/2024:13:53:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1051 "-" "python-requests/2.31.0" "54.147.33.181" response-time=6.521
54.147.33.181 - - [16/Nov/2024:14:09:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1051 "-" "python-requests/2.31.0" "54.147.33.181" response-time=8.710
last few lines of error log
2024-11-12 19:35:13,388: OSError: write error
2024-11-12 19:35:13,388: OSError: write error
2024-11-12 19:35:13,389: Error running WSGI application
2024-11-12 19:35:13,393: RuntimeError: The gevent-websocket server is not configured appropriately. See the Deployment section of the documentation for more information.
2024-11-12 19:35:13,393:   File "/home/taupirho/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1498, in call
2024-11-12 19:35:13,393:     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
2024-11-12 19:35:13,393:
2024-11-12 19:35:13,393:   File "/home/taupirho/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_socketio/init.py", line 43, in call
2024-11-12 19:35:13,393:     return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).call(environ,
2024-11-12 19:35:13,394:
2024-11-12 19:35:13,394:   File "/home/taupirho/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/engineio/middleware.py", line 63, in call
2024-11-12 19:35:13,394:     return self.engineio_app.handle_request(environ, start_response)
2024-11-12 19:35:13,394:
2024-11-12 19:35:13,394:   File "/home/taupirho/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 433, in handle_request
2024-11-12 19:35:13,394:     return self.eio.handle_request(environ, start_response)
2024-11-12 19:35:13,394:
2024-11-12 19:35:13,394:   File "/home/taupirho/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/engineio/server.py", line 281, in handle_request
2024-11-12 19:35:13,394:     packets = socket.handle_get_request(
2024-11-12 19:35:13,394:
2024-11-12 19:35:13,394:   File "/home/taupirho/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 90, in handle_get_request
2024-11-12 19:35:13,395:     return getattr(self, 'upgrade' + transport)(environ,
2024-11-12 19:35:13,395:
2024-11-12 19:35:13,395:   File "/home/taupirho/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 146, in _upgrade_websocket
2024-11-12 19:35:13,395:     return ws(environ, start_response)
2024-11-12 19:35:13,395:
2024-11-12 19:35:13,395:   File "/home/taupirho/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/engineio/async_drivers/gevent.py", line 54, in call
2024-11-12 19:35:13,395:     raise RuntimeError('The gevent-websocket server is not '

Not sure what happened but it seems to be back up now. Maybe some weird timing issue

It looks like you had a typo in the url -- see: https://taupirho/pythonanywhere.com (mind the slash after the username-subdomain part...).

If you're on a free tier, please note that your web app might go to sleep if no request is made to it for a while. Just as you said, you didn't visit the web app for weeks until recently. If this happens, simply reload your web app or make a request for it to be live again.
Your best bet would be to set up an automated task that makes regular request to your web app. Also note that pythonanywhere servers are being rebooted from time to time for maintenance purposes. Simply making a request to your web app will load it and make it live again.
Lastly as noted by @caseneuve, you probably inserted a slash (/) in your subdomain whereas it should be a dot (.).
See https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/31994/#id_post_107082
